# How do I make this object an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm using a function so it won't modify the original values in the array.

```
function timeDropDowns() {
  return [
    '12:30am', '1am', '1:30am', '2am',
  ];
}

var someVar = timeDropDowns();
console.log(typeof(someVar)); // returns Object
```

typeof(someVar) is an object. How do I make it an array? Thank you

Comment: Arrays are objects. Try `console.log(someVar instanceof Array)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)

> The JavaScript **`Array`** object is a global object that is used in the construction of arrays; which are high-level, list-like objects.

are still objects with special features, like `length` property, so you need better to test with [`Array.isArray`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray).

The answer is, you have already an array.

(Just a hint, [`typeof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) is an operator and it does not need parenthesis for using.)

```js
function timeDropDowns() {
    return [
        '12:30am', '1am', '1:30am', '2am',
    ];
}

var someVar = timeDropDowns();
console.log(typeof someVar); // returns Object

console.log(Array.isArray(someVar)); // returns true
```

Comment: Why javascript return `Array` as object. You can read here:http://javascript.crockford.com/remedial.html